# zIndex of imgAreaSelect jquery library is not working in IE

Tags: jquery-plugins

Is z-index in CSS is not supported by IE? I'm using the [imgAreaSelect](http://odyniec.net/projects/imgareaselect/) jQuery library to select some portion of an image. My code works fine in Chrome and Mozilla but it's not working in IE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For positioned elements IE6 and IE7 do not support z-index as expected. Use position:relative and z-index:1 for parent element.

http://www.quirksmode.org/bugreports/archives/2006/01/Explorer_z_index_bug.html

http://www.last-child.com/conflicting-z-index-in-ie6/

Comment: ok. I tried this but still getting same output. Is there any solution to this problem.